# Construct 2 - No puedo solucionar el sistema de carga de armas

Tags: game, google-play-games

Estoy creando un juego con construct 2 y tengo algunos problemas con lo que es la carga de las balas.

Conseguí que cargue 8 balas en el arma cuando el jugador posea mas de ocho balas y que cargue las que le quedan cunado tiene menos de ocho. El problema es que no consigo que las ponga de una en una. Use el evento Wait de System, intente con every X seconds y tampoco lo puedo hacer funcionar. Fui poniendo una en una y en cada una le metía un wait pero no va. Alguien que use el programa y tenga alguna idea?

Saludos!

[image: My event sheet]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Las preguntas en este sitio deben ser en español.

Comment: Gracias por traducir la pregunta, Yamil, te recomiendo agregar el código y el (o los) error(es) que puedas tener.